# Tracking items checked while looping through a ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox, parallel.foreach

I have a list view like this:

```
<ListView Name="FinalListView"
                  SelectionMode="Multiple"
                  SelectionChanged="FinalListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="400"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

As you can see the list view's each item contains a checkbox, But below is my Parallel.Foreach loop to iterating with my loop and work with the items.

**Please let me know, how can not which item is checked, and not checked in the loop as below** :

**FinalFileNames -> IS the Collection. i.e. the data source for the listview.**

```
Parallel.ForEach(FinalFileNames,
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                    path =>
                    {
                        -----code ------------
                    });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To Find the Checked Items in your List
Have a Boolean property to bind the check Box,

```
foreach (TheObjectYouBindedForYourList item in FinalFileNames )
{
  if (item.Checked== true)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using Parallel.Foreach, in which I am not able to get Checked property.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Checked property to the objects in your FinalFileNames collection. I see you are already binding to the properties ID and Name in your XAML, so I will assume this is not a collection of primitive types. So if your class looks something like this:

```
public class FileName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

add a Checked property to it

```
public bool Checked { get; set; }
```

Then in your XAML you can add a style which binds the IsSelected property of the ListViewItem to the Checked property of your object.

```
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Checked}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

Now the Checked property will be set on your FileName object whenever the ListViewItem is selected and it can be checked in your Parallel.ForEach code:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(FinalFileNames,
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                path =>
                {
                    if (path.Checked)
                    {
                       // code
                    }
                });
        });
```